# Javascript recursion not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

I ported this method from Java to Javascript. With an "original" array with 9 objects in it, the Java code made 3000 subarrays of size 4.

In this javascript code I get 6 subarrays of size 9.

```
var hitterArray = new Array();

function permute(level, permuted, used, original){

    if (level == 4) {
        hitterArray.push(permuted); //array of arrays
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
            if (!used[i]) {
                used[i] = true;

                permuted.push(original[i]);

                permute(level + 1, permuted, used, original);

                used[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want 3000 subarrays of size 4, why is that not working?

This is how I initialize the permute function:

```
            var used = new Array(results.length);
            for(p = 0; p < used.length; p++){
                used[p] = false;
            }
            var permuteArray = new Array();

            permute(0, permuteArray, used, results);
```

Insight appreciated

Comment: You might run into a callstack limitation which massive recursion often encounters. What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is on your for loop, you need to declare the `i` with `var` otherwise you make it a global variable.

```
for(var i = 0; ....
```

Another thing which might have impact is that you are always passing references to the arrays: `used` and `permuted` that is likely to have some impact on the result, consider cloning the arrays with `array.slice()` to create new copies of them.

And also I think the permutations of 4 objects out of 9 should be 3024 (9*8*7*6), so you should get 3024 arrays of 4

### edit

```
function permute(level, permuted, used, original){

    if (level == 4) {
        hitterArray.push(permuted); //You don't need to create a copy here, but if performance is not an issue, you might want to do it, for clarity
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
            if (!used[i]) {
                var newused = used.slice();
                var newpermuted = permuted.slice();

                newused[i] = true;

                newpermuted.push(original[i]);

                permute(level + 1, newpermuted, newused, original);

                //used[i] = false; //this won't be needed as you've just created a copy of the original one
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly would I use `array.slice`,  in the function calls?

Comment: I think the best place is before making changes to the arrays, see my edit.